# Find if a column exists in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I check if a column exists in a HTML table using JQuery.

I am creating a dynamic table on my server side and need to check if a column exists in the HTML table and execute a call back based on that.

Comment: Post relevant HTML/JS and show us what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can create an HTML table dynamically, you can attach an id or class to every column.

you can get the amount of specific elements with: `$('element').size();`
so you can check if this equals zero or not.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just give each  an id once the server returns the columns and then just do a

```
$("#idhere")
```